# How to write teamplate for handler

Tags: php, phpmailer

Handler not processing select with name="ordertype". I try write normal code, where is my mistakes? Help me please, thank you for spending your time!

https://pastebin.com/mbmiapg2 (rd-mailform.tpl)

https://pastebin.com/mL1HdhhS (rd-mailform.php)

```
 <!-- RD Mailform-->
              <form data-form-output="form-output-global" data-form-type="contact" method="post" action="bat/rd-mailform.php" class="rd-mailform text-left">
                <div class="form-group"><span class="icon material-icons-person"></span>
                  <label for="contact-name" class="form-label">Full name</label>
                  <input id="contact-name" type="text" name="name" data-constraints="@Required" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"><span class="icon material-icons-markunread"></span>
                  <label for="contact-email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                  <input id="contact-email" type="email" name="email" data-constraints="@Email @Required" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"><span class="icon material-icons-phone"></span>
                  <label for="contact-phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
                  <input id="contact-phone" type="text" name="message" data-constraints="@Numeric @Required" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group"><span class="icon material-icons-add"></span>
                  <!--Select 2-->
                  <select data-placeholder="Тип заявки" name="ordertype" data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" data-constraints="@Required" class="form-control select-filter">
                    <option value="">empty</option>
                    <option value="2">Консультация</option>
                    <option value="3">Заказ</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-salem">Оставь заявку сейчас!</button>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rd-mailform.php file, you've got an underscore in your variable name, so you're assigning the details to a new variable that isn't being used. You are also missing a `#` on your `OrdertypeState` tag.

You've got

```
$_template= str_replace(
        array("<!-- {OrdertypeState} -->", "<!-- #{FromOrdertype} -->"),
        array("Ordertype:", $_POST['ordertype']),
        $template);
```

instead of

```
$template= str_replace(
        array("<!-- #{OrdertypeState} -->", "<!-- #{FromOrdertype} -->"),
        array("Ordertype:", $_POST['ordertype']),
        $template);
```

Comment: Thank you! In rd-mailform.tpl all is normal? :)

Comment: You're also missing a `#` on your OrdertypeState tag, I'll update my answer.